# Solspace Importer stops at £ character

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

I have the Solspace importer module working well using DataType: CSV Importer. However it won't import data into a custom field past a **£** character. For example:

Data to import: `Price Guide £300,000 - £315,000`

After import, field contains: `Price Guide`

I've tried using both **None** and **XHTML** text formatting for the custom field.

Am I missing any settings? or do I need to encode characters before import?

(EE 2.10.1 and Importer 2.2.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required that the .CSV file match the encoding of your data table.  Most likely this is UTF-8.

My workflow with Importer includes the step where I open the .CSV file in a text editor (I use BBEdit) and save the file as UTF-8 and Windows Line endings (CRLF).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the file in question was 'Windows Latin 1'. As this is a daily import process I contacted the webhosts to automate the conversion of file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

guessing here, but it might be something to do with allowed characters.you'll have to search what file/setting to set that, cause i don't remember